# how to access single JSON value for key in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary, syntax

I am new to Obj-C and somehow I can get the output of a JSON-Request due to difficulties with arrays, dictionareis and syntax. It would be great if someone could get me on my way.

```
    NSLog(@"JSON Feed: %@", self.classified);
    NSDictionary *test = self.classified;
    NSLog(@"andy %@", [test objectForKey:@"text"]);
```

this throws an exception :

JSON Feed: (
        {
        text = "test text";
    }
)
2014-06-05 17:25:28.170 Nerdfeed[2321:4107] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b988da0
2014-06-05 17:25:28.173 Nerdfeed[2321:4107] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception

I now tried to find a solution for hours but cant fix it. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON? And also what code you're using to read and parse it into the property `self.classified`

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then understand that NSLog of arrays/dictionaries looks *almost* like the matching JSON, except that `()` rather than `[]` is used around arrays, and a few other minor details.  Your "JSON Feed" is an array of a single element, with that element being a dictionary containing the single entry "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.classified` seems to be a `NSArray` with a single item (and not a `NSDictionary`). Try `[[self.classified firstObject] objectForKey:@"text"]`

Comment: That might be the case, however the syntax is not OK. XCode tells me that there is no visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'firstObject'

Comment: OK! Got it, I still had the variable declared as dictionary. Your help and the comment from Hot Licks helped to sove it. Thank you!